# Edit action in controller not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

When I edit an item and return to the index view the item doesn't show what I updated it to.

I think I know what the problem is but not sure how to fix it. In my service class I have a CreateEditItem method and when I step thru the code it hits the if condition <=0. So it acts like there is an id of 0 when I click the submit button to submit my update. I'm not sure what to do to fix this. Do I need to have a separate method for Edit? And if so what should that look like?

```
  public bool CreateEditItem(Item item)
    {

        if (item.ItemId <= 0)
        {
            var maxId = _mockList.Max(p => p.ItemId);
            item.ItemId = maxId + 1;

            _mockList.Add(item);
            return true;
        }


        var itemToEdit = _mockList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ItemId == 
        item.ItemId);

        itemToEdit = item;
        return true;

    }
```

Action in Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditItem(Item itemToEdit)
    {
        _itemService.CreateEditItem(itemToEdit);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { id = 
       itemToEdit.ItemId });
    }
```

View:

```
        <div class="row">
                <form asp-action="EditItem">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text- 
            danger"></div>
                    <div class="container form-group">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">As Of : <label 
           for="AsOf" /></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><input id="AsOf" 
         value="@Model.ItemToEdit.AsOf" name="AsOf" type="date" /></div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">Title Summary : <label 
           for="TitleSummary" /></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input id="TitleSummary" 
         value="@Model.ItemToEdit.Title" name="Title" type="text" /></div>
                        </div>                        

                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="submit" 
                    value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" /></div>                               
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

I expect when I click the submit button to submit my update it will show the updated Title and/or AsOf date.

Comment: Does the item that gets passed into your controller have an id of zero? Debug the code and step through there and report back the results.

Comment: It shows a new id, instead of the id I'm editing. For example, I'm editing id 11 and when i debug it shows id 13. Like it is adding a new record instead of updating.

Comment: Are you actually wanting the id to be updated to something else? The id should stay the same and some other field should be changing is generally best practice.

Comment: Just an FYI here, it looks as though the way you are handling an invalid id is to just increment it based on the value of the largest id. You probably want to be throwing an error there rather than just finding the max id and incrementing it.

Comment: It looks like your code is not calling SaveChanges().

Answer (score 0):

change your method from `HTTPut` to `HttpPost`
it will work.

Comment: which method the controller action?

Comment: where you have put the method in your controller